# How to pandas groupby and pivot_table to have pivto tables look like Excel's

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have this dataframe that I have to turn into a pivot table. No problem. Pandas offers pivot / pivot_table which allow to create nice pivot tables but there are some features of Excel I can't seem to replicate.

which ones? the mid-way aggregates (the aggregate sums seen in `division_sac_ac` ) and obtained through

```
slice_ac = df.groupby(by='ac').sum()
slice_sac = df.groupby(by='sac').sum()
```

How can I integrate the 3 (pivot, slice_ac, slice_sac) objects ?

**EDIT: partial result but still not satisfactory (partial because I could integrate `slice_sac` but not `slice_ac` - and generally the aestetichs of it all is miles away from excel):**

```
table_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['ac','sac'], values='value', columns=['name'], aggfunc=[np.sum], margins=True)
print(table_df.stack(['name']))
```

which yields:

```
                        sum
ac     sac    name         
bond   Corp   omega    0.05
              All      0.05
       Govt   lambda   0.05
              rho      0.20
              All      0.25
equity Europe alfa     0.05
              beta     0.05
              gamma    0.10
              All      0.20
       US     epsilon  0.20
              All      0.20
All           alfa     0.05
              beta     0.05
              epsilon  0.20
              gamma    0.10
              lambda   0.05
              omega    0.05
              rho      0.20
              All      0.70
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

division_sac_ac = {'equity': ['Europe', 'US'], 'bond': ['Corp', 'Govt']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'record_1': ['alfa', 'Europe', 'equity', 0.05],
'record_2': ['beta', 'Europe', 'equity', 0.05],
'record_3': ['gamma', 'Europe', 'equity', 0.1],
'record_4': ['epsilon', 'US', 'equity', 0.2],
'record_5': ['rho', 'Govt', 'bond', 0.2],
'record_6': ['lambda', 'Govt', 'bond', 0.05],
'record_7': ['omega', 'Corp', 'bond', 0.05], }, orient='index')

df.columns = ['name', 'sac', 'ac', 'value']

table_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['ac','sac','name'], values='value', aggfunc=[np.sum])

slice_ac = df.groupby(by='ac').sum()
slice_sac = df.groupby(by='sac').sum()

print(table_df)
print(slice_ac)
print(slice_sac)
```

`table_df` does the job but I'd like to integrate also mid-way results (`slice_ac, slice_sac`) as shown in this picture:
[image]

whereas my output is more like:

```
                        sum
ac     sac    name         
bond   Corp   omega    0.05
       Govt   lambda   0.05
              rho      0.20
equity Europe alfa     0.05
              beta     0.05
              gamma    0.10
       US     epsilon  0.20
        value
ac           
bond      0.3
equity    0.4
        value
sac          
Corp     0.05
Europe   0.20
Govt     0.25
US       0.20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate `table_df`, `slice_ac` & `slice_sac` by having empty values (or a placeholder value like 'subtotal') as the index value for the aggregated columns, e.g.

```
slice_ac = table_df.groupby(level=0).sum()
slice_sac = table_df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()

slice_ac.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, '', '') for i in slice_ac.index])
slice_sac.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, j, '') for i, j in slice_sac.index])

pd.concat([table_df, slice_ac, slice_sac]).sort()
```

will output

```
                       sum
ac     sac    name
bond                   0.30
       Corp            0.05
              omega    0.05
       Govt            0.25
              lambda   0.05
              rho      0.20
equity                 0.40
       Europe          0.20
              alfa     0.05
              beta     0.05
              gamma    0.10
       US              0.20
              epsilon  0.20
```